# Having trouble with console output displaying left to right as opposed to vertical

Tags: java, console, output

Basically it's my first day of coding and I'm having trouble understanding printing into the console. I want my output to be vertical where each string displays beneath the previous, but right now they're going from left to right.

I've tried putting everything in loops to see if maybe Java has to work in a loop to indent into the next line but it didn't work.

```
    public class Sales_Tax 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.print("Sales Tax Rates");
    System.out.print("---------------");
    System.out.print("Alaska Tax Rate: 0.0%");
    System.out.print("Hawaii Tax Rate: 4.0%");
    System.out.print("Arizona Tax Rate: 5.6%");
    System.out.print("Florida Tax Rate: 6.0%");
    System.out.print("Vermont Tax Rate: 6.0%");

    }
    }
```

how do I make it vertical like I have written in eclipse?

The current output is as follows:

```
Sales Tax Rates---------------Alaska Tax Rate: 0.0%Hawaii Tax Rate: 4.0%Arizona Tax Rate: 5.6%Florida Tax Rate: 6.0%Vermont Tax Rate: 6.0%
```

Comment: you are missing `\n` in your output strings, or use `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.println() instead of System.out.print().

When you use a method, like System.out.print(), take a look at the javadoc to know what it does exactly, especially when it does not work as you thought.

Comment: Okay thank you! I actually made it work by adding \n at the end of every string too!

Comment: Note that \n is system specific, Windows in particular uses another couple of characters at end of lines. You should rather use System.lineSeparator() to be system agnostic.